# Python: Importing "Text" from typing package

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I trying to import `Text`from `typing` by,

```
from typing import Text
```

I am getting the following error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'Text'
```

I am working on Python 3.5

Any advice?

Comment: `rm ./typing.py`

Comment: Or, less tranchant, `mv ./typing.py ./my_typing.py` ...

Comment: And when you just `import typing`? Does this work?

Comment: @Vinny Yes `import typing` works fine

Comment: After you import typing, is Text class available using `typing.Text` ?

Comment: @gboffi Thank you so much, `mv ./typing.py ./my_typing.py` is working. But I was supposed to restart python after changing `typing.py` name.      @Vinny Thank you for the help :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known problem with Python 3.5.0 and 3.5.1 - see https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/1838 and https://github.com/awslabs/aws-encryption-sdk-cli/issues/114.
As they say there, you can add try/catch blocks around the typing imports - or you can use an updated version of Python.